# How to extract data from pdf files to a single csv file using python (pandas..)

Tags: python, pandas, csv, pdfplumber

so i need to build a model that extract data from pdf files(Resumes) (OCR) so i collected bunch of pdf files and i need to convert them to suitable form for OCR and i am lost. i tried converting them to a csv file with Regex but no use the csv file is empty if there's anything you guys can help me with that would be great. Thank you in advance!
this is my code :

```
import pdfplumber
import os
import re
import pandas as pd

def clean_text(text):
    cleaned_text = re.sub(r"[^a-zA-Z0-9\s@.-]", "", text)  # Remove special characters except alphanumeric, @, and -
    cleaned_text = re.sub(r"\s+", " ", cleaned_text)  # Remove extra spaces
    return cleaned_text.strip()

def extract_data_from_resume(pdf_path):
    with pdfplumber.open(pdf_path) as pdf:
        text = ""
        for page in pdf.pages:
            text += page.extract_text()

    cleaned_text = clean_text(text)

    name_pattern = r"Name:\s*(.*)"
    name_match = re.search(name_pattern, cleaned_text, re.IGNORECASE)
    name = name_match.group(1) if name_match else ""

    email_pattern = r"Email:\s*([^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@]+)"
    email_match = re.search(email_pattern, cleaned_text, re.IGNORECASE)
    email = email_match.group(1) if email_match else ""

    phone_pattern = r"Phone:\s*(.*)"
    phone_match = re.search(phone_pattern, cleaned_text, re.IGNORECASE)
    phone = phone_match.group(1) if phone_match else ""

    return name, email, phone

def convert_pdf_to_csv(directory, output_csv_path):
    data = []
    for filename in os.listdir(directory):
        if filename.endswith(".pdf"):
            pdf_path = os.path.join(directory, filename)
            name, email, phone = extract_data_from_resume(pdf_path)
            data.append({"Name": name, "Email": email, "Phone": phone})

    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df.to_csv(output_csv_path, index=False)

# Example usage
directory = 'D:/data/test'
output_csv_path = 'D:/data/test/test.csv'
convert_pdf_to_csv(directory, output_csv_path)
```

Comment: OCR would require an image. Converting the PDF to a csv would destroy the image, making it useless for OCR

Comment: so i have to convert my pdfs to an image ?

Comment: you have to be able to convert the OCRs from an image. There is an error in your PDF to Text routine if you aren't getting anything in your csv.